# When using CSS modules, why would this fail in a global context?

Tags: sass, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

core.scss

```
:global {

  $color-white: #fff;
  $color-primary: #6d5cae;
  $color-black: #000;
  $mix-percentage-dark: 81%;

  @mixin button($text-color, $background-color, $border-color) {
    .open .dropdown-toggle#{&} {
      background-color: mix($background-color, $color-black, $mix-percentage-dark);
      border-color: mix($background-color, $color-black, $mix-percentage-dark);
      color: $text-color;
    }
  }

  .btn-primary {
    @include button($color-white, $color-primary, $color-primary);
  }

}
```

WebPack Config:

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: cssModulesRegex,
  loaders: [
    'style?sourceMap',
    'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader',
    'resolve-url',
    'sass?sourceMap'
  ]
})
```

Error:

> Module build failed: CssSyntaxError: postcss-modules-local-by-default:
>   src/styles/core.scss:1:0: Missing whitespace before :global :global {

Comment: Can you understand where that `:global :global` is coming from? Here's the failing package btw, https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-modules-local-by-default . Perhaps you can simplify your example to get a better idea.

Comment: Please provide `postcss` config.

Comment: The error is the same with the postcss-loader removed.